# Overland flow modeling Help

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, spatial-analyst

I  would like to determine the surface ﬂow network, this based on the spatial analysis of DEM data and the creation of separate layers for surface ponds and preferential surface ﬂow pathways.
More accurate I would like delineation surface pond and surface flow pathway over urban areas based on DEM.
I want to know what software I can automatically calculate?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want surface flow pathways for a DEM? Do you also need catchment areas? Since it's an urban area, is it necessary to consider a storm water drainage system?

Comment: Yes I want to determine surface flow pathway and surface pond, based on DEM and I construct catchment areas.
Now, I want to determine only surface modeling, without coupled with drainage system.
I want to create urban drainage modelling  that requires a detailed representation of
the overland flow network of ponds and pathways to reliably represent surface retention storage and flowpaths.

Answer (score 2):

I think there's an extension to ArcMap for what you want to do, even if that is a bit unclear to me. 
I would use [Arc Hydro Tools](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/07/16/arc-hydro-tools-for-10-1-beta-now-available/), just  make sure you get the latest version for 10.1 from the ftp ([link at bottom](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/61799-ArcHydro-update-for-ArcGIS-10.1)).

You can find a number of partial workflows [here](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/74711-quot-Flow-Direction-with-Sinks-quot-is-missing?p=262220#post262220) for different situations.

AHT has the ability to include lakes and streams in the calculations, and it will return both catchment areas and flow paths based solely on the DEM.

If you need to include a drainage system, AHT doesn't have a functionality for this out of the box. I have done this by simulating the pipes as creeks (burn them in to the DEM with *DEM Reconditioning*), but there are probably alternative ways of accomplishing the same thing. It will assume you have a "sufficient amount" of inlets to the pipes in order for this generalization to be valid.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I will used ArcHydro tools I hope to solve the problem.